# Using simple past in the present tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Could someone please explain why we can say:

It is time the law **reflected** this ("dognapping" as a serious crime) in the sentencing of all offenders.

is it the same as:

It is time the law **reflects** this  ("dognapping" as a serious crime) in the sentencing of all offenders.

Comment: Sentence 1 - *It is time the law reflected this...* - is correct. Although it uses the past tense it means what sentence 2 says. **But** sentence 2 is not idiomatic. "It is time" is usually followed by either the past tense or by "for"+subject+infinitive: *It is time for the law to reflect this...*

Comment: Thanks for that. What is this sort of grammar called and is there some sort of list with phrases that are usually followed by either the past sense or by "for"+subject+infinitive?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Source? Both seem natural to me here in Canada

Comment: @gotube: [Here's one:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/it-s-time). Maybe it's pondian. Do you say. "It's time I go home" or "It's time I went home"?

Comment: I don't know of a list, but the past tense is used in hypothetical contexts. *I wish* and *if only*: "If only (or I wish) it **wasn't** raining." "I wish I **could** join the orchestra." To speak about the past: "If only (or I wish) it **hadn't** rained." "I wish I could have joined the orchestra." [Here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/wish-and-if-only) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/wish). (Both at the British Council.)

Comment: [for_subj+inf]: "They called/campaigned/voted etc for him to resign". "It was necessary for him to speak". This usage is very common. You could try Googling "For him to", "For me to" etc.

Comment: @Gottano: Do visit the link in my reply to gotube above btw.

Comment: Thanks again Old Brixtonian. To sumarise we use the past in the present with: "It is time", "Wish/if only" and "for+subj+inf".  Are there any other situations that you can think of? Im not including the modal verbs "could" and "would" here as modal verbs are just... different beasts, haha.

Comment: As I said above, "It is time" is usually followed by **either** the past tense **or** by "for"+subject+infinitive". The latter is off topic!

Comment: Yes, there are other words signalling a hypothesis: "if", "supposing" and "what if" for example. And there is: "I'd rather" ("I would rather"), signalling a **preference**. Don't be deterred by its modal: just learn is as "I'd rather"! These are well explained [here](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/unreal-past/) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would-rather-would-sooner). Be aware that the word "rather" also has quite different uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original sentence about "dognapping" was very long.
Shorter examples are easier to work with.

> - It is time that the law **be** enforced.
> - It is time that the law **was** enforced.
>
> ---
>
> - It is time that the government **was** honest in its dealings.
> - It is time that the government **become** honest in its dealings.

When you want something about the world to change, you also usually wish that the world had been that way in the past.

|  | About the present | About the past |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | It is time that the house **be made** clean | It is time that the house **was** clean |
|  | I would like the house to stop being dirty right now | I would like the dirtiness of the house to be a thing of the past |

"It is time that the program **ended**" implies that we wished that the change happened earlier.

"It is time that the program **end**" does not show whether you wanted the change, or proposed event, to happen in the past, or if you only wanted the change to occur in the present.